# Did Nahor marry his niece, or is the text implying that it was a "different Haran"?

Tags: genesis

Closely related: [Who is Iscah in Genesis?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/5707/who-is-iscah-in-genesis)

Genesis 11:27, 29:

> ...Terah fathered Abram, Nahor, and Haran; and Haran fathered Lot... And Abram and Nahor took wives... the name of Nahor's wife, Milcah, **the daughter of Haran the father of Milcah and Iscah**.

Was this Haran the brother of Nahor and Abram, or was the text trying to imply that it was a "different Haran" when it refers to Haran as "the father of Milcah and Iscah"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did Nahor marry his niece?

Yes, he did. At that time, it was not that unusual. In fact, Abram married his half-sister.

Genesis 20:12

> Besides, she really is my sister, the daughter of my father though not of my mother; and she became my wife.